# Classification of data transmitted from java socket

Tags: java, tcp

I want to pass different types of information from the client to the server via socket TCP (data transfer, prompt the server to call a function, ...) and they are on different threads, each receiving and transmitting a different type of information.

I'm passing data strings that have an integer added to the front to mark and use Switch-Case to classifying when received.

```
"1 This is a message" ---> Chat:"This is a message"
"2 asd"               ---> function2("asd")
"3 Object1={{...}}"   ---> Update object Object1
```

I think this way is not good. Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not use gRPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you're looking for is **[Network Packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet)**. Each packet has a [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing)) and a payload. You can think of each packet as containing an id to separate different packets from each other, as well as a length that determines the size of the incoming payload. Definitely checkout **[Netty](https://netty.io/)**, they do a lot of the work for you, including their amazing [ByteBuf](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html). Here is an example of how that might look.

```java
byte[] payload = "Hello world!";

int length = payload.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

Packet packet = new Packet(1, length, payload);

client.send(packet);
```